# Function's url staying after a new render

Tags: python, django

I have just started learning Django after completing the tutorial on their website and I am trying to get my Django website's form to render a template with a dictionary describing the "login_error" variable after a login attempt has failed. This works fine but the URL still contains the view functions name and I don't want this. Redirecting the page to itself works fine but then I cannot define the "login_error" variable.

The URL to start the views login function:

`path('login_user', views.login_user, name='login_user'),`

If the login fails I am re-rendering the page like so:

`return render(request, 'sign_in/sign-in.html', {
    'login_error': "We couldn't find an account with that email and/or password."
})`

Here is what I am using to navigate to this function:

`<form class="sign_in" method="post" action="{% url 'sign-in:login_user' %}">`

Here are some **images** to help explain what's happening:

- I submit a bad login:

  [image]
- This is the part of the URL stays after the render:

[image]

Any advice, links or resources to direct me in the way of a solution would be highly appreciated as I have been searching for hours now and still can't find anything related to this issue, thanks!

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you showed the complete view and any other related URL patterns. Your behaviour looks like the typical approach in Django. If there is an error with the form then stay on that URL, re-render the form and display the errors. If you don't like `login_user` in the URL, then change the path to `path('', views.login_user, name='login_user'),`.  If you really want to redirect, then use the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/) and then return a redirect, but this is an unusual approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst this will be subjective, displaying an error message on the same page which generated it makes a considerable amount of sense both from UX and effort required to program the handling of these messages outside of the request context (e.g. a redirect).

If however, your use case is that you must 100% redirect to another page which shows the error, you might want to look at Django's messages framework: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/